# JRE not showing up in "Open with" list

Tags: minecraft

I am trying to install minecraft on to my computer and i was able to do everything except change the .jar to "Open with" JRE. JRE does not appear in the list of programs

-Running ubuntu 13.04

-Have JRE 6/7

Comment: Which JRE do you have installed?  OpenJDK or Sun/Oracle Java?

Comment: OpenJDK is what i am running

Answer (score 1):

Open /usr/share/applications and look for a file named "OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime". If it doesn't exists create a file named /usr/share/applications/openjdk-6-java.desktop with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime
Comment=OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime
Exec=cautious-launcher %f /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java -jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=openjdk-6
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true
```

You should change the "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java" part of Exec to the location of java on your system. Then reboot and the option should be there.

Comment: I have found the file, and it is there. Now what?

Comment: Same for me, but I'm running Debian. The file is there, but it doesn't appear as an option when I right-click nor does it appear on the menu. The links are pointing to the right places, I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It should give you the option to do "Open with another application" if you right click the thing.  You can then hit "Other applications" and look for OpenJDK 6/7 or similar runtime environment and that *should* work and allow you to select to run the `minecraft.jar` with the OpenJDK runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with OpenJDK 7 and solved it by doing the following. By the way, I'm running Debian SID, so the same solution probably applies.

See if you have **./openjdk-7-java.desktop** in one of the the following locations: **/home/YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE/.local/share/applications** or **/usr/share/applications**. You may need to enable `show hidden files` option.

If you do have it:

1. open the file
2. locate the line that says: `Exec=`
3. go to the end of the line
4. add a whitespace and the following: `%f`
5. save the file

E.G.

You find the following file:

> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Name=OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
>
> Comment=OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime
>
> Exec=/usr/bin/java -jar
>
> Terminal=false
>
> Type=Application
>
> Icon=openjdk-7
>
> MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
>
> NoDisplay=false

Just change the line that starts with `Exec=` to the following:

> Exec=/usr/bin/java -jar %f

Now it should work fine.

If you don't find the file in any of those locations:

1. Try reinstalling OpenJDK and check again
2. Try creating a file as
       Joren suggested