# How to open Minecraft.jar?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble opening Minecraft.jar because there is no java runtime in open with listed. Even though I have installed it. This seems to be the solution [JRE not showing up in "Open with" list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322694/jre-not-showing-up-in-open-with-list) But I don't understand how I'm supposed to make the file hes talking about. I right clicked in  /usr/share/applications/ but it didn't give me an option to make a file.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What JRE did you install? You need OpenJDK 7 from the Software Center.

Comment: I installed OpenJDK 7 from the Software Center.

Comment: Did you reboot after you installed it? Also make sure that, under Mnecraft.jar>Properties>Permissions, the executable permission is ticked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Java with this commands and you have an entry in <kbd>Open with</kbd>:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

And in order to do things more easily, use the *Minecraft Installer*.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

Then run Minecraft from the Dash.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.

Comment: @Seth OK, voted for close

Comment: Tried with openjdk8 and it didn't work. Then installed oracle java9. It didn't work. Then I installed java8  and now it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make a `run.sh` file in the directory with the `Minecraft.jar` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
 java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

or anywhere you like changing `Minecraft.jar` to the correct filepath. Mark the file as executable and run it.